# JAXB 2.0 - how to marshal static inner classes

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, jaxb2

In JAXB 2.0 if you compile a schema to java classes and a class contains an inner class, are you required to do anything different while building your content tree from the generated classes?

If so, what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it requires any special treatment.

Comment: Well, I posted the above question because it is (possibly, if I'm on the right track) a condensed version of an earlier question that hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: If you could take a look at that one for me -- I'd be very grateful.  This is the link to it:  [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855067/jaxb-2-0-how-to-marshal-static-inner-classes [/link]

Comment: I believe you mean that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853701/jaxb-2-0-marshal-the-marshalling-appears-to-be-ignorning-some-elements-what-a .Anyway, it is very difficult to see what you have there. try to give a staright-forward example.